# How can I load a local version of a javascript file instead of a remote version?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to load a webpage with a huge javascript file.

```
<script src="js/sample.js"></script>
```

I cannot change the html file, but i can download the javascript file to my Application.

```
NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.demo.url/index.html"];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Everytime I start my App the chached javascript file have to reload again. Maybe I have the wrong cache settings.

Two possible solution:

1. Cache the javascipt in the right way. Do not delete on app close.
2. Manual download javascript file and use it.

Comment: are you just trying to initially load that javascript file, what happens on 2nd load, same file or new refreshed file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Implement an own NSURL Protocol:

NSURLProtocolCustom.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface NSURLProtocolCustom : NSURLProtocol<NSURLConnectionDelegate> {
    NSMutableData *responseData;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLConnection *connection;
@end
```

NSURLProtocolCustom.m

```
#import "NSURLProtocolCustom.h"
@implementation NSURLProtocolCustom
+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    if ([[request.URL lastPathComponent] isEqualToString:--Your precached file--]) { 
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

+ (NSURLRequest *)canonicalRequestForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    return request;
}

- (void)startLoading {
    NSString* file = --Your local file--;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];
    NSURLResponse *response = [[NSURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:[self.request URL] MIMEType:@"text/javascript" expectedContentLength:-1 textEncodingName:nil];
    [self.client URLProtocol:self didReceiveResponse:response cacheStoragePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed];
    [self.client URLProtocol:self didLoadData:data];
    [self.client URLProtocolDidFinishLoading:self];
}

- (void)stopLoading {
}
```

And your request

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:--your URL-- cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:50.0];
[NSURLProtocol registerClass:[NSURLProtocolCustom class]];
```

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to inject javascript?

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

if you are trying to load local html file for the 1st time, add it to the bundle and call it liek this:

```
NSURL *relativeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
NSURL *u = [NSURL URLWithString:@"xxx.html" relativeToURL:relativeURL];
```

and then when you need to reload you do a normal uiwebview request method call!